# Group name not showing on production

Tags: django, wagtail

Im using Wagtail and i want to display the user group name in the admin. On local server everything works fine and the group name is displayed as expected. I tried adding this to the template but none work on production all worked local:

```py
{{ user.groups.all }}
{{ user.groups.all.0 }}
{{ request.user.groups.all }}
{{ request.user.groups.all.0 }}
```

Comment: Does the user belong to any groups? It is possible that a user simply does not belong to any group, hence `{{ request.user.groups.all.0 }}`, will not display anything.

Comment: Yes, it dose user belongs to a group. But thanks for trying to help :) @WillemVanOnsem